# loading R objects and creating graphs with rscript

Tags: r

I am loading all the `.RData` files in a directory one at a time.  Depending on the objects within the `.RData` files, I want to create graphs.  But the `print` statement returns `NULL` so my assignment statement to `x` is not working.  What am I doing wrong?

```
for (i in dir("c:\\data", pattern = "^data"))
{
    tmpenv <- new.env()
    load(i, envir=tmpenv)

    for (y in ls(envir=tmpenv))
    {
        x <- tmpenv$y
        print(head(x))
    }
}
```

Comment: @Andrie, I've update the code. That addresses the ls part but I am not able to load the objects.

Comment: You'll have to show us what type of data you've got.  Generally speaking, `print` does not create a graph.  Also, you say your "assignment statement to x is not working," but you're not doing any assignment in the code provided.  Finally, there's a syntax error: It should be `tmpenv[[y]]`, not `tmpenv$y`